# How to create envelope from template with checkbox tab data?

Tags: docusignapi

DocuSign has a mountain of great documentation when it pertains to Java, Ruby, Node.js, C# and the like, but their documentation is relatively light on sending raw JSON requests.  I have a template that has checkbox tabs and I need to be able to create a document to sign with prefilled checkbox data.  No examples exist on how to do that with a raw JSON request.

How do you create an envelope from template with checkbox tab data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After reverse engineering the format from the `/accounts/$accountId/envelopes/$envelopeId/documents/$documentId/tabs` endpoint, I was able to discover that the `checkboxTabs` node of your request must look like this:

```
"checkboxTabs": [
    {
       "tabLabel": "ACCESSORIES",
       "name": "LIGHT_USB_C_ADAPTER",
       "selected": "true"
    }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

Glad you found the answer. Just wanted to point out that we do show how to make direct JSON calls in both our reference material as well as in our code examples. We use bash scripts with curl to make these calls, so you may see "Bash" or "CURL" in the title of the language when you look up our code examples. 
For your case you can dinf it here - https://developers.docusign.com/esign-rest-api/code-examples/set-envelope-tab-values

Comment: You have numerous bash scripts with cURL, but I could not find ANY examples with checkboxTabs requests for creating an envelope from a template.  There are many examples of dynamically **creating** templates with checkboxTabs, but not filling one out.

Comment: got it, sorry about that. Let me know if you need any other assistance.

Answer (score 0):

Just wanted to add, You can always visit corresponding SDK Method documentation in DocuSign website. For Envelopes::createEnvelope method, refer - https://developers.docusign.com/esign-rest-api/reference/Envelopes/Envelopes/create
You will see the definition of the checkbox and use the available options accordingly.